# Git big commit best practices

Tags: git

I'm using git and been working heavily on my local repository the last week.

I like to make many small commits (like 2 o 3 files) instead of big ones, but this time between time pressure and that the change involved many files, I've got a whole lot of files unstaged.

My question is, what is the best practice in this scenario? Is there any tool that lets me divide the work in small commits?

**Note that I do know** how to stage files one at a time and make the small commits by hand, but I'm afraid to make a mistake and create a commit that leaves the code in an inconsistent state (like not compiling or working badly).

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git add -i` should help you divide commits to chunks, then `git stash` rest of code, check if everything works, `git commit`, `git stash pop` and loop.

Comment: The key here is `git stash`; the OP says he already knows how to divide commits, though do note that `-p` (`--patch`) is often more useful than `-i` (`--interactive`).

Comment: Jefromi, the OP says he knows how to stage *files on at a time*.

Comment: I like to use `git add -i` and then select `p (patch)` from the interactive menu... this way you can stage chosen hunks of various files all in one go. Then, double-check with `git diff --cached` before the commit.

Comment: I use git add -i  with patch, but I verify compile and operation with 'git stash save --keep-index'  see the git stash documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can stage part of a file with `git add --patch`. This should allow you to commit sets of related changes, without committing other unrelated changes that occur in the same files.

And if you want to test the current `HEAD` without losing all your uncommitted work, `git stash` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I find `git add -i` a bit cumbersome to work with as I find it hard to see what it is actually doing.

However, `git gui` turns out to be quite good at per-hunk and also per-line staging and unstaging. Occasionally it needs a little support by doing a quick temporary edit before staging and then immediately reversing the edit, but most of the time `git gui` works really well for me.