# Best practice to stage files in git

Tags: git, staging

I am looking for a better description of staging files with git itself (other than 
[Git big commit best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113305/git-big-commit-best-practices)).
I don't need to *stash* files into smaller commits, ignore files by pattern, etc.
What I am looking for is a tutorial that is only about adding files - efficient by browsing through big packs (up to 100) of "unstaged" files and maybe editing them (as hunks).

Command line tricks with pipeline filtering like in

```
git status -uno --porcelain | gawk '{ print $2 }' | xargs echo | xargs git add
```

are offtopic.

Bottom line: I am looking for tips to "master" interactive mode and patterns in staging with

```
git add
```

Comment: Pipes aren't "command line tricks". They're integral to using your tools correctly and effectively. By ignoring them you're crippling yourself.

Comment: Pipelining should not be a primary choice, if there is a shorter way (native functionality). My question concerns itself with finding such an alternative with git itself. Please note, it is not about 5-10 files, it is about staging 40-50 of them and they don't have a trivial masking subset. Pipelining costs time to debug up to precise result. That's why I excluded this option from the start. Simply not good enough, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to the command line. You're not going to enjoy your stay with that attitude.

Comment: @meagar IMO You are completely missing the point ;) My question is about learning git not pipes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why is

```
git add -p -- some/dir
```

not good enough?

There is also git-gui

Hope this helps

Comment: yep, *git gui* seems to address the problem. But best would be actually a link to blog or a tutorial for an interactive mode.

Comment: It looks like I was looking for this explanation of interactive mode (http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_adding.html), including the revert case.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that now I use in my daily git business

```
git commit -a
```

or if I need to make choices the interactive mode with

```
git add -i
```