# Does tidying your code warrant an individual Git commit?

Tags: git, git-commit, code-readability

It is established that each individual Git commit should be a *single logical change*. It is also established that this production process is often messy (see [sausage-making](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/#sausage)) and should not be hidden away - Seth Robertson advocates *["Commit often, perfect later"](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/)*.

I find that at some point, either at the end of a project or at the end of a series of related commits, I need to tidy my code, especially if I have been engrossed in a problem and working quickly. By *tidy* I don't mean logical changes that affect the actual workings of the program, but rather things like:

- Clarifying comments
- Changing the order of functions to improve readability
- Correcting indents/whitespace
- Deleting old tests like `// console.log(variables)`

My question is then: **is it best practice to save these 'cosmetic' changes in a separate individual commit? (And if not how should they be committed?)**

Note that I'm not inviting *opinion* on this. Surely there is an established best-practice; the article above emphasises [enforcing standards](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/#enforce), so it's important to know what those standards are.

As well as Seth Robertson's article I've read the following existing questions, but I can't find my question addressed anywhere:

- [Git-commit-best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543913/git-commit-best-practices)
- [Git-big-commit-best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113305/git-big-commit-best-practices)
- [Git-best-practice-commit-logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655374/git-best-practice-commit-logs)

Comment: commit cosmetic changes separately.  It helps in problem isolation later, since you can usually skip the entire cosmetic-changes-only commit, when looking for a bug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19656336/6194839

I found this while looking through your links, as I agree that there should be a standard.

Here is what I want to highlight from that link:

<type>(<scope>): <subject>
<BLANK LINE>
<body>
<BLANK LINE>
<footer>

Designate a <type> of your commit as cosmetic.

Comment: @BryceDrew I see what you mean. Your comment prompted me to find other examples of reputable style guides that list various commit 'types' and a recommended prefix to the commit messages. For example https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#git-commit-messages (prefix 'art:' for style changes) and https://udacity.github.io/git-styleguide/ (prefix 'style:'). This tends to suggest that there IS a convention of style changes being a valid commit. I'd add these references as an answer but unfortunately the question is on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cosmetic changes should be separate. They are a logical change separate from the functional changes. Also, it makes it easier to review the functional changes.